# Suppose we declare an array as: int a[10]; then what is a?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, language-lawyer

Basically this question appeared in a college test of mine (I know we shouldn't ask test questions here but this is a theoretical test question) which was like:

> 1. Consider the following declaration.
>
> ```
> int a[10];
> ```
>
> Which of the following is true? ........................ [1]
>
> (a) `a` is a variable.
>
> (b) `a` is a constant.
>
> (c) `a` is a pointer to an integer.
>
> (d) None of the above.

Answer given by the professor's team is (d) None of these. Please help.

Comment: "_Answer given [...]_" given by you or as correct answer? You could also add your reasoning on each possibility.

Comment: I don't know what is the correct answer! I just know that whosoever has marked D will be getting full marks in this question.

Comment: To meet the Stack Overflow guidlines, you should not post text as images.

Comment: So whoever is in charge of that test thinks that an array is not a variable...Sounds if someone should be fired.

Comment: `D` is obvious nonsense. Your professor is rather bad

Comment: @ecneics what is the name of your college (and its location)?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are weird.

Given the declaration

```
int a[10];
```

you get the following in memory (`?` represents an indeterminate value, assuming this is an `auto` array):

```
   +–––+
a: | ? | a[0]
   +–––+
   | ? | a[1]
   +–––+
    ...
   +–––+
   | ? | a[9]
   +–—–+
```

There is no object `a` separate from the array elements themselves.  You cannot assign a new value to `a` by itself; the compiler will reject code like

```
a = some_other_array_name;
```

Under most circumstances the *expression* `a` will "decay" to a pointer to the first element (equivalent to `&a[0]`).

So, is `a` a variable or not?  The problem is that the term "variable" is kind of sloppy with respect to C.

In C, you have *objects* (regions of memory that can potentially store values) and *lvalues* (expressions through which objects can be read or modified).  The expression `a[i]` is an lvalue - it can be used to assign a new value to an object (the `i`th element of the array):

```
a[i] = 42;
```

However, there are things called "non-modifiable" lvalues that designate objects but cannot be the target of an assignment.  Array expressions like `a` are non-modifiable lvalues.

Since the *expression* `a` by itself cannot be the target of an assignment nor can you read the contents of the array through it, I would say D is a viable answer.  But since `a` designates a region of storage that can be modified (just not through the expression `a` itself), A is also a viable answer.

I suspect your professor is using "variable" to mean "can be the target of an assignment", which is why they consider D to be the correct answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the rationale for `T x[N]` syntax over `T[N] a` syntax?

Comment: @pmor: Declaration mimics use.  If we have an array of `T` named `x` and we want to access the `i`'th element, we use the array subscript operator `[]` - `a = x[i];`.  The *expression* `x[i]` has type `T`, so it follows that the declaration is written `T x[N];`.  Put another way, the operand of `[]` is `x` in both the declaration and the expression.  Same reasoning holds for pointer and function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. `a` - is a variable.
2. `a` decays to a pointer to an integer when used in expressions, but it is not a pointer.

Comment: 2. is not a possible answer, it simply means that C is not correct. What about `a` being a constant? `a = ...` is invalid, so in my opinion `a` is a constant, but of course the elements of `a` are not.

Comment: @mch is not constant as `a` is the whole array (all elements) which are not constant. It dacays to pointer in expressions (which confines you in this case).  `a = ...` is invalid not because `a` is constant, but for a completely different reason.  Point 2 is to explain what `a` in expression is.